# Android How to remove Empty Space

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to remove empty space. For example: `rama chan dran` should become `ramachandran`.

Comment: Cant you write directly **ramachandran......** instead of **rama chan dran.....**. What is the problem ?

Comment: @Dinesh Sharma: I think that's an example he gave.

Comment: Your string is "rama chan dran..." or its like "rama chan dran is going back to home blah blah blah" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String s = "rama chan dran.....";
s = s.replace(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a Java question than Android specific, but have a look at:

[public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 2):

Use **replaceAll()** method of String class.
For Example:

```
String s = "Test Test Tes t";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(" ", "");
```